# How can I change thickness on elycharts pie chart?

Tags: svg, charts

I'm trying to make a menu for a website, and the client has provided me the final view of the menu: three circles, one in another, divided into segments. And each segment is a link, which will load content with AJAX.

So, I'm playing with Elycharts, and managed to make the three circles and divide them into segments. The main difference between the current version and the desired result is that the three circles must be different in thickness ... but can't find a way to control this ...

What is the way to achieve this? Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with d3.js, much simpler ... and generates simpler code too ;)